# Help understanding javascript convention

Tags: javascript

I see JQuery plug-ins and other javascript library documents set up like this:

```
(function($,window,undefined){
    ...plug-in code...
});
```

Why is it necessary to wrap the script in a function, and what args does can that function receive?

Answer (score 6):

The args received are:

```
(function($,window,undefined){
  //..
})(jQuery, window);
```

**`$`**: A reference for the jQuery object, often made for being able to refer to it as the `$` alias, since in the outer scope the code might be in "compatibility mode".

**`window`**: The `window` argument is often used to *shorten* identifier lookup. In browser scripting `window` is a property of the global object, in order to resolve it, the Identifier Resolution Process has to inspect every scope, until it reaches the global scope. If we add `window` as an argument, the lookup will be short, no matter how nested is our function.

In non-browser scripting environments, the `window` identifier doesn't even exist, and that pattern is a common way to keep track of the Global object, e.g.:

```
(function (global, undefined) {
  //..
})(this);
```

Note that the `this` value for *global code* (not function code), always refers to the global object.

**`undefined`**: At last but not least, the `undefined` argument, it is used as a "security measure", because `undefined` is also a property of the Global object, and in the ECMAScript 3rd Edition Specification, its value is mutable, immagine:

```
undefined = true;
```

That would mess up with your code, but if we have an argument, and we don't pass anything to it, it will hold the *undefined value*.

Fortunately that was fixed on the ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification, `undefined`, `Infinity` and `NaN` are not writable anymore. :)

Comment: wow, I had no idea about the undefined bit there.  strange that undefined is mutable.

Comment: `typeof myVar == "undefined"` is pretty much the safest comparison to use, but it's good that this safety measure is in place.

Comment: @Matt, Yeah, was something bad on ECMAScript 3, `undefined` is not a *Literal* as `null`, `true` or `false`, is a writable property of the global object :(

Comment: so... what you're saying is that in ECMAScript 3, undefined is, well, defined. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The only scope in Javascript other than global, is function scope. Wrapping a block of code in a function is the only way to ensure that your variables don't leak out into the rest of the code

The only way that function can receive arguments is if it's called as soon as it's defined (in fact, that's the only way this function will ever have its code executed):

```
(function($,window,undefined){
    ...plug-in code...
})(jQuery,this,...);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is in the doc :

> to make sure that your plugin doesn't
>   collide with other libraries that
>   might use the dollar sign, it's a best
>   practice to pass jQuery to a self
>   executing function (closure) that maps
>   it to the dollar sign so it can't be
>   overwritten by another library in the
>   scope of its execution.

Read here : http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring